# How to SPARQL select all living politicians from EU political parties on Wikidata?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Can somebody, please help me write a SPARQL query, which would select all currently living politicians, whose political institutions are from a country within the EU?

Currently I have 3 queries, but I don't know how to combine them

The first one checks for people who are living, whose occupation is politician and/or who are a member of a political party

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?politician ?politicianLabel

WHERE {

  ?politician wdt:P106 wd:Q82955 .  

  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?politician wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}

  OPTIONAL {
    ?politician wdt:P102 ?membership .
  }

  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?politician wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}

  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }

}
```

The second one shows all EU countries

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel

WHERE {

    ?country wdt:P463 wd:Q458

   SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }

}
```

And the third one finds parties from a specific country

```
SELECT ?party

WHERE {

  ?party wdt:P31 wd:Q7278

  ?party wdt:17 #EU Countries#

}
```

But How can I combine these queries? Can somebody help?

Thank you

Comment: ehm, just combine those triple patterns and reuse the variables such that you have them connected?

Comment: like this: `?politician wdt:P106 wd:Q82955 .  
  ?politician wdt:P102 ?party . 
  ?party wdt:P31 wd:Q7278 .
  ?party wdt:P17 ?country .
  ?country wdt:P463 wd:Q458

  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?politician wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}`

Comment: Oh.. Ok...

Well I tried that 
`SELECT DISTINCT ?politician
WHERE {
?politician wdt:P106 wd:Q82955 .
OPTIONAL {
 ?politician wdt:P102 ?membership .
}
?politician wdt:P102 ?party .
?party wdt:P31 wd:Q7278 .
?party wdt:P17 ?country .
?country wdt:P463 wd:Q458
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?politician wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}
}`

But I get "query timeout reached"

Any ideas how to optimize the query so that it could give a result?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: @AKSW I also tried switching them around to start with the country, but no luck. 

`?country wdt:P463 wd:Q458.
?party wdt:P31 wd:Q7278 .
?party wdt:P17 ?country .
?politician wdt:P106 wd:Q82955 .
?politician wdt:P102 ?party .
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?politician wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @AKSW

This works:

```
WHERE {
?country wdt:P463 wd:Q458.
?party wdt:P31 wd:Q7278 .
?party wdt:P17 ?country .
?politician wdt:P106 wd:Q82955 . hint:Prior hint:runFirst true.
?politician wdt:P102 ?party .
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?politician wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}
}
```

If you start with the country and add the

```
hint:Prior hint:runFirst true.
```

line, it is optimized enough to give result.

Comment: yeah, sometimes you have to "help" the query optimizer. Just switching around the triple patterns won't usually help as long as there is some query optimization after parsing. And the order of triple patterns in a basic graph pattern doesn't matter, only once you have OPTIONAL (aka left join) or other stuff like BIND and MINUS etc